# Syntax and semantics of implications with different arrangement of propositions

Tags: grammar, semantics

I have two statements

1. If swimming is allowed in the shore, then sharks have not been spotted.
2. If sharks have not been spotted, then swimming is allowed.

I am a maths student, so based on that these two are different. But semantically both of these sounds correct to me, that is, swimming is allowed at the shore when there is no evidence of sharks being present.

Are these two statements syntactically same as well?

Comment: This is a matter of investigating differing semantics (meanings) rather than syntax. // (2)  gives a condition that must be met for swimming to be allowed: a rule. (1) is a deduction based on the assumption that the rule is being adhered to and the observation that inshore swimming is allowed at this time.

Comment: _In the shore_ is not idiomatic English, though there is a word [inshore](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/inshore).

Comment: Hi @KateBunting I fixed the sentence.

Comment: No, in the shore is still there. near the shore is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. is a statement of something that may be inferred (no sharks spotted) from the fact that swimming is still allowed.
2. is a broader statement, that says that in all cases where sharks haven't been spotted, swimming is allowed - even if the jellyfish are waiting for you.

Your restatement is equivalent to 2.

They are both if... then constructs, but the meanings are different.

Comment: So the syntax (if..then) was same, semantics (meaning) is different.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences are not equivalent.  They are a classic example of what is known as *illicit conversion*.  That is, the truth of sentence 2 is not entailed by the truth of sentence 1 or vice versa. If the truth of a proposition P entails that a proposition Q is not true (ie is false), then the truth of proposition Q entails that the proposition P is not true:  P and Q cannot both be true.  That is why the OP states that something is wrong.

What seems to lie in the background is a *rule* or *regulation*.

> 2. If a shark is spotted, stay out of the water!

Or it might be for the lifeguards, and say

> 2. If you spot sharks, get the swimmers out of the the water!

These, set out as imperatives, are not quite as easy to reverse.  It might be something like

> 1. If everyone's been made to get out of the water, then a shark had better have been spotted!

As Jack O'Flaherty has pointed out, there is an implication in the sentences that spotting a shark might not be the only reason for keeping people away from the sea:  there might be an orca, or sewage or a naval mine etc.  That in turn shows how careful we must be to avoid illicit conversion.